# PageMethods with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pagemethods

I have found ASP.Net PageMethods very handy and easy to use, but I have just started developing using MVC and am not sure how to use them?

What is the equivalent of `PageMethods.MyFunction()` in MVC where MyFunction is a Controller  action?

I know I can use the `Json` function to return a value, but how do I call the action from the client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know I can use the Json function to
>   return a value, but how do I call the
>   action from the client?

I think you're looking for either [getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON)

```
$.getJSON("/controller/action", function(json)
{
  alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
});
```

or the [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) jQuery method.

Either can call an action and get JSON data back from ASP.NET MVC very easily.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need page methods. Page methods in asp.net are a way to expose methods in the page class to your client-side code.

In MVC, you don't have a page class, so you can just issue an XHR to a url (../controller/action/params, or whatever), and return JSON from the action.

**Update**:
After re-reading your question, it sounds like you want to know *how* to issue an XHR from the client. In raw javascript, you can just use the XMLHttpRequest object, but whatever JS library you are using probably has a nicer wrapper. jQuery's, for instance, is [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

Comment: Thanks, if I have the url for the action with parameters how do I execute this while being able to access the returned Json value.