# respond to an ajax call in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have some javascript files and an html file.  The do some stuff, and I'd like to make an ajax call (using jQuery's $.post() method) to a server to get some info, and then do some more stuff.  Do I need to set up some sort of scaffolding before I can do this?  I have a .cs file now, can I just run that with VC# and have it respond to the requests? I'm not sure where to begin.  I've looked a little for tutorials... but the ones on microsoft.com are old; Thanks!

23890123890

**Update**: I believe this is ASP.NET MVC

Comment: are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: I think MVC, I'll update the ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using webforms, you can look at [Page Methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

I'm guessing you might be using MVC though, which you may want to refer to this question: [PageMethods with ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369595/pagemethods-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I just finished this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript but still don't know what any of it means.  It just told me to click a bunch of things.  How can I add a controller method that will accept and respond to ajax calls?  I'll be wading through the ms docs in the mean time

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html that should help you build a controller that returns you something besides a `View`

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you're not using MVC would be to use WCF to create a service which can receive the jQuery ajax requests. The project at http://wcf.codeplex.com/ has some support for jQuery $.ajax calls.